# Threading in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have a very basic doubt in vb.net threading.
I am having a function MyFunc1() which actually launches a form and asks for input from the user and returns a string. The return must be done only when user clicks a button called 'return' in the Form.

So I framed the function like this.

```
Public done as Boolean = true
Public str as String

Function MyFunc1() As String
  Start Thread1  //launch UI as seperate thread
  While done
  End While    //Infinite loop to hold the parent loop till done is made as false
  return str
End Function

Function Thread1
  //code to launch UI
End Function

Function onClickReturn  //Function triggered when 'return' is pressed
  str = EditText.text
  done = false
End Function
```

The problem right now is Thread1 launches the UI but once the UI is launched Thread1 dies and so does the UI Panel.

Any ways to fix this?

Comment: There is no reason to bother with threads. The vast majority of Windows Forms implementations only ever need the single UI thread.

Comment: In the code above "Code to launch UI" is something complicated. It launches the UI but returns back the control. That is the issue. It is not blocking.

Comment: I still maintain that you are over-engineering this. If you need to launch a form that blocks the main UI, then follow @Kratz's answer below. "Code to launch UI" could just as easily be called in that UI's form_load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do doesn't event need threads. Since your blocking the original thread anyways, there is really no need to create a second thread.  Typically you just call

```
MyForm.ShowDialog()
```

That shows a modal dialog and will block the calling code at that line, allowing the UI to be displayed and used until the user dismisses it.

Comment: In the code above "Code to launch UI" is something complicated. It launches the UI but returns back the control. That is the issue. It is not blocking.

Comment: It the "Code to launch UI" not something you can change? Can you not change the UI code you are launching? Unless you change that code or at least get back a `Form` object of the launched UI, I'm not sure you can achieve this.

Comment: I can easily get back the Form object but what good will it do?

Comment: I could say in your thread if you have the form object you can do like `While myForm.Visible Application.DoEvents`, so your thread at least would wait till the form closes before ending. Still, the best way is to find the `Form.Show` call and change it to `Form.ShowDialog`

Comment: You are right. I was thinking complicated. It was easy. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a .Net thread object, you can block by calling [Thread.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta.aspx).